# canPerformAction not called in Mac Catalyst app until app enters background

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

I have a Mac Catalyst application with a layout like

```
UISplitViewController
    |
    |––––– Sidebar
    |
    |
    |––––– List VC
    |         |
    |      *on tap*   
    |         |
    |––––– Detail VC
```

I have an NSToolbarItem setup like

```swift
let item = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
item.image = UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
item.label = "Edit Item"
item.action = #selector(DetailVC.editSelectedItem)
item.target = nil
return item
```

That's how Apple set things up in their tutorials on NSToolbarItem in Mac Catalyst apps.

Then they say that in your Detail VC, you can enable the item like

```swift
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(editSelectedItem) {
        return true
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Issue is, `canPerformAction` *isn't* called *until* my application is no longer in the foreground, for instance if I go back to Xcode or any other app.

When I come *back* to my app, *canPerformAction* isn't called again, and my toolbar item becomes disabled.

Comment: Hey Will did you resolve this? I'm encountering a similar issue where `canPerformAction` isn't being called to refresh when I present a detail view controller, not until I do something to trigger it like background the app or click in that view controller. Wonder if we need to programmatically force a refresh somehow.

Comment: Hey Jordan, I did resolve this but it's a little complicated. Do you have Twitter? I could send you a sample project.

Comment: Thanks Will, thought I'd note the workaround to force validation in case it's helpful to someone else :) `toolbar.perform(NSSelectorFromString("validateVisibleItems"))`